# How to display a list of objects sharing the same attribute?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am still new to Java and learning how things work and I am currently stuck in my project.

I have created a java class to store objects (cars), with the following attributes:

- make
- model
- color
- mileage
- price

I have gone as far as displaying all these objects, and sorting them according to one of their attributes (ascending or descending).

However, I am trying to find a way to display only the cars that match a specific attribute, let's say color ("*I only want to display the green cars*") and I will need to sort them afterwards ("*Only the green cars, sorted by mileage*").

I have been looking at tutorials and code snippets but I can't seem to understand how to achieve this.

Can someone point me in the right direction ? Which method/function should I use?

Comment: Show us the work you did

Comment: Show us your code, so it's easier for us to help you, to see what the solution nest fits your code, and for you to have a complete solution that does not need any adaption.

Comment: Can you write code that tell you whether a given instance should be displayed? Can you write code that applies the same logic to all the instances? Given those two steps, can you solve the problem? If not, why not? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? You are expected to make some attempt to solve the problem. We can only help you get un-stuck if you show us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code it is pretty difficult to understand where you've gone wrong at.

However, using your explanation I got what I could - you want to get all the `Car` objects that share a specific attribute. The way we can achieve this is by traversing through the array that holds all the `Car` objects and compare if that specific attribute(eg: the colour) is equal to a certain value(eg: green).

```
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfCars.length ; i++)
        {
            if(arrayOfCars[i].getColour().equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
            {
            }
        }
```

And if the condition is true we can store that object in an `ArrayList`.

```
        ArrayList<Car> greenCars = new ArrayList<>() ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfCars.length ; i++)
        {
            if(arrayOfCars[i].getColour().equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
            {
                greenCars.add(arrayOfCars[i]) ;
            }
        }
```

There you go! Now you have an `ArrayList` that stores all the cars that are green.

Note: you can use an `Array` instead of an `ArrayList`. But remember when creating an `Array` you must define its size and the program does not know how many green cars are there - that's why I used an `ArrayList`. Sure, you can define the size of `Array` that stores the green cars as the same as the size of the `Array` that stores all the cars. But the new `Array` may end up having `null` elements. If you haven't worked with an `ArrayList` before, you might find [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) helpful.

Alright, now that we've got an `ArrayList` of all the green cars you can sort the `ArrayList` in ascending or descending order of any of the `Car` attributes(eg: mileage). I'm not going to show you how this is done as you said

> I have gone as far as displaying all these objects, and sorting them according to one of their attributes (ascending or descending).

So yeah, I'm sure you can do that on your own.

Here's the main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList ;

public class CarsMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // create an array of Cars
        Car[] arrayOfCars = new Car[4] ;
        arrayOfCars[0] = new Car("red", 14400) ;
        arrayOfCars[1] = new Car("green", 13000) ;
        arrayOfCars[2] = new Car("green", 15000) ;
        arrayOfCars[3] = new Car("blue", 13500) ;

        // use a for loop to get the cars that are green and store them in an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Car> greenCars = new ArrayList<>() ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfCars.length ; i++)
        {
            if(arrayOfCars[i].getColour().equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
            {
                greenCars.add(arrayOfCars[i]) ;
            }
        }

        // display the green cars
        for(int k = 0 ; k < greenCars.size() ; k++)
        {
            System.out.println((k+1) + ". colour = " + greenCars.get(k).getColour() + " | mileage = " + greenCars.get(k).getMileage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the `Car` class that I used:

```
class Car
{
    private String make, model, colour ;
    private int mileage, price ;


    public Car(String c, int m)
    {
        this.colour = c ;
        this.mileage = m ;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour ;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage)
    {
        this.mileage = mileage ;
    }

    public String getColour()
    {
        return this.colour ;
    }

    public int getMileage()
    {
        return this.mileage ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stream`. Just filter with predicate by the color and then sort all by the mileage.

```java
public class MavenMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Car> greenCar = car -> "green".equalsIgnoreCase(car.getColor());
        Comparator<Car> sortByMileage = Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getMileage);
        List<Car> cars = List.of();
        List<Car> res = cars.stream()
                            .filter(greenCar)
                            .sorted(sortByMileage)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

class Car {

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private int mileage;
    private int price;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thank you all for your answers, mostly @user1105, @mcroteau and @oleg.cherednik!

I did not provide my code because I thought you guys would just tell me which method to use, not provide the whole code :-)

Next:

- I will try to add my objects to an ArrayList : I want to be able to add new cars to the list and I'm not sure a simple Array will be the right option since I need to increase its length each time I add an object.
- I need to learn how to format the results so they show up without the brackets and all that, create a new line after each object...

Here is my code, hope someone finds it useful for their own purpose. I am using Android Studio, hence the buttons, textView...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnRed, btnBlue;
TextView tvResult;

public static class Car{
    public Car(String color, String model, Integer mileage){
        this.color = color;
        this.model = model;
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    String model;
    String color;
    int mileage;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", mileage=" + mileage +
                '}';
    }

    // just in case I need it in the future
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // these are buttons and a textview used in my app
    btnBlue = findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
    btnRed = findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
    tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);


    Car[] allCarsList = new Car[27];
    allCarsList[0] = new Car("Red", "Mercedes", 124500);
    allCarsList[1] = new Car("Blue", "Mercedes", 45321);
    allCarsList[2] = new Car("Red", "Audi", 76142);
    allCarsList[3] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 210367);
    allCarsList[4] = new Car("Blue", "Peugeot", 97000);
    allCarsList[5] = new Car("Yellow", "Audi", 3451);
    allCarsList[6] = new Car("Red", "BMW", 100320);
    allCarsList[7] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 54677);
    allCarsList[8] = new Car("Red", "Mercedes", 8543);
    allCarsList[9] = new Car("Yellow", "Audi", 342);
    allCarsList[10] = new Car("Blue", "Audi", 4321);
    allCarsList[11] = new Car("Red", "Peugeot", 7242);
    allCarsList[12] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 908);
    allCarsList[13] = new Car("Blue", "Peugeot", 8776);
    allCarsList[14] = new Car("Yellow", "Audi", 90089);
    allCarsList[15] = new Car("Red", "BMW", 145678);
    allCarsList[16] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 24324);
    allCarsList[17] = new Car("Red", "Mercedes", 76598);
    allCarsList[18] = new Car("Red", "Ford", 5564);
    allCarsList[19] = new Car("Blue", "Mercedes", 4336);
    allCarsList[20] = new Car("Red", "Audi", 65543);
    allCarsList[21] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 95634);
    allCarsList[22] = new Car("Blue", "Audi", 23142);
    allCarsList[23] = new Car("Yellow", "Ford", 87334);
    allCarsList[24] = new Car("Red", "Tesla", 2143);
    allCarsList[25] = new Car("Green", "BMW", 675);
    allCarsList[26] = new Car("Red", "Mercedes", 976);

    //when "Blue" button is pressed
    btnBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayList<Car> blueCars = new ArrayList<>() ;
            for(int i = 0; i < allCarsList.length ; i++){
                if(allCarsList[i].getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("Blue")){
                    blueCars.add(allCarsList[i]);
                }
            }
            Comparator<Car> comparatorMileage = Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getMileage);
            blueCars.sort(comparatorMileage);

            //display the Red Cars list, sorted by mileage on the textview
            tvResult.setText(blueCars.toString());

        }
    });

    //when Red button is pressed
    btnRed.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayList<Car> redCars = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < allCarsList.length ; i++){
                if(allCarsList[i].getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("Red")){
                    redCars.add(allCarsList[i]);
                }
            }
            Comparator<Car> comparatorMileage = Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getMileage);
            redCars.sort(comparatorMileage);

            //display the Red Cars list, sorted by mileage on the textview
            tvResult.setText(redCars.toString());
        }
    }));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Unicorn {

    public static class Car {
        public Car(String color, String model, Integer mileage) {
            this.color = color;
            this.model = model;
            this.mileage = mileage;
        }

        String model;
        String color;
        Integer mileage;

        public String getColor() {
            return this.color;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return this.model;
        }

        public Integer getMileage() {
            return this.mileage; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car bmd = new Car("blue", "BMW", 13);
        Car audi = new Car("blue", "Audi", 10);
        Car volkswagen = new Car("red", "Volkswagen", 142);
        List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList(new Car[]{bmd, audi, volkswagen});

        Comparator<Car> comparator = new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
                return a.getMileage().compareTo(b.getMileage());
            }
        };

        Car[] sortedFiltered = cars.stream()
                .filter((car) -> car.getColor().equals("blue"))
                .sorted(comparator)
                .toArray(Car[]::new);

        for (Car car : sortedFiltered) System.out.println(car.getModel());

    }
}
```